# Converting int, double to char array in C or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to convert int to char array and double to char array. Any way of doing this in C or Objective C.

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of turning an integer into a string using `snprintf`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something or learn how to do something?  Either is possible here.

Comment: What I want is if int is converted to char then the resulting char array should be of 4 byte (assuming int size 4 byte) and same for the double.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to treat the number as an array of `char`, you can take the address and cast the pointer:

```
int i;
double d;
char * ic = (char *) &i;
char * dc = (char *) &d;
```

then `ic` and `dc` are pointers to `char`.  They aren't zero-terminated, so you can't use them as strings, but they can be used as arrays.

Answer (score 2):

For another interpretation of what "converting" means, use

```
union double_or_bytes { double d ; char bytes[8] ; } converter;

converter.d = <the double you have> ;

<do what you wanted to do with> converter.bytes ;
```