# COnverting Char Array to Long int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, char, long-integer

How to convert Char array to long in obj c

```
 unsigned char *composite[4]; 
composite[0]=spIndex;
composite[1]= minor;
composite[2]=shortss[0];
composite[3]=shortss[1];
```

i need to convert this to Long int..Anyone please help

Comment: Please check these links maybe they will be of help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169925/how-to-do-string-conversions-in-objective-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609972/converting-int-double-to-char-array-in-c-or-objective-c

Comment: So you want those 4 strings concatenated and then converted to an integer?  Or did you perhaps mean `unsigned char composite[4]` instead?

Comment: i am trying to do something similar to this `(new BigInteger(1,composite))` which is in java code

Comment: In java byte array composite value is [1, 9, 0, 10] and 
BigInteger comp = new BigInteger(1,composite); this gives
17367050 value i am not getting this value.my composite value is [0] 0x00000001,[1]0x0000005a,[2]0x00000000,[3]0x0000000a

Comment: And how do you hope to hold this value once you've converted it (given it's 128-bit)?  You will need to implement your own version of `BigInteger` and this conversion is just one small part of that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at converting what is essentially already a binary number then a simple type cast would suffice but you would need to reverse the indexes to get the same result as you would in Java: `long value = *((long*)composite);`

You might also consider this if you have many such scenarios:

```
union {
  unsigned char asChars[4];
  long asLong;
} value;

value.asChar[3] = 1;
value.asChar[2] = 9;
value.asChar[1] = 0;
value.asChar[0] = 10;

// Outputs 17367050
NSLog(@"Value as long  %ld",value.asLong);
```